# Android OpenGL 2 ES how to generate an infinite 3D grid

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Hello I am quite new to OPEN GL ES android.

My task is to generate a 3D grid terrain that is infinite.

The task is tree planting. I am using an RTK system of pretty accurate coordinates that I convent into UTM and then mark points on my lines in the grid.(I won't go into further details).

I want to be able to draw virtual lines that are `n` metres away from each other on my screen using a given scale, for example `3 metres` in the real world may be equal to `0.3` on the screen, my problem is if I have an area of `6 square kilometres` in the real world, this will definitely require that my grid on the device is scrollable.

So how do I come up with an infinite scrollable 3D grid in order to solve that problem on android?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Infinite terrain seems to be impossible, so I would say dynamically generated terrain. You must have some standard grid with size greater then screen size. When you reaching the bound of this grid while scrolling, you have to shift it back to center, and then reload textures and other stuff for this grid.

Comment: Alright,
Makes sense.
I'll try this and then come back.